# Why does magento use xml files for themeing?

Tags: php, xml, magento

I am new to Magento and studying its documentation. Excuse me if I sound a bit to much against it but I am open minded. I don't understand why Magento uses XML for theming. What's the reason behind it?

I am running the newest version 1.6 from the SVN repo and following [this site](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/0_-_theming_in_magento/designing-for-magento).

I read that I need to create local.xml declaring what gets in and out of the theme. After I did the basic structure then added my theme directory through the backend. I removed a elements on the front end using a few xml elements

Example:

```
<remove name="right.poll"/>
<remove name="right.permanent.callout"/>
<remove name="left.permanent.callout"/>
<remove name="paypal.partner.right.logo"/>
```

<del>The homepage doesn't change... why is this? Is there another location that would need modification?</del>
 I found out that i needed to disable all caching for dev only.
(for those that dont know its (admin page) -> system -> cache management -> select all and disable)

I also don't understand why the CSS/JS/media directory is completely separate from the template directory. It makes no sense why they would do this. Another thing I don't understand is why there are a million directories (sarcasm) that I need to get into to make a modification. I assume they are using some kind of MVC model but it is by far nothing I have ever seen. If they are attempting to make pretty URLs with all these directories I'm pretty sure they have heard of htaccess. (again excuse me if I sound ignorant but I am new).

PS., I looked into the phtml files and most of them look like their just calling these XML elements, is it possible to use plain old HTML and PHP to create a theme? Or am I forced to use their XML methods?

edit: the theme folder at app/design/frontend has two folders base and default which im thinking each of these are interfaces for example a group of themes i would like to use. i modified the design_change db table from default/default to base/default (also done on the admin page but i like the db better). i saw that a different page was rendered. so i figured i can just take out the base folder because its extra confusion. when i did that the site broke. so it looks like magento has tied two theme directories into this application. its as if they are just as confused as we are. am i right?

Please let me know your input.

Thanks.

ps: i found out magento is from the zend framework.

Comment: Note: to others wanting to know, i found out why my xml modifications weren't updating. I had to go to the backend and click system->cache management and disable all of them but only for development. when you go into production enable them all back.

Comment: I would highly recommend taking the free online developer training first. Will give you a lot of information that you will spend ages trying to find yourself. Register on magentocommerce.com

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your answers, in turn:

> "I don't understand why Magento uses XML for theming."

In many MVC systems, determining what content and data are available in the view means dealing with (creating & customizing) controller actions. Layout XML gives even frontend developers the ability to add and remove view elements and their data ("Blocks" in Magento) to different routes without having to rewrite action controller classes.

> "I read that I need to create local.xml declaring what gets in and out of the theme."

Not necessarily. If you have no customizations of layout XML, you won't need a local.xml file. Moreover, if you have layout XML customizations for ONLY the homepage, you can add your layout update XML to the page data via the CMS admin.

> "[W]hy [is] the CSS/JS/media directory is completely separate from the template directory[?]"

This is simply a security feature. All files under `./skin` can be directly accessed via the browser, and all files under `./app` *cannot* be accessed via the browser, including theme-related files under `./app/design`. Is this a logical, developer-friendly strategy? Not at all, and Magento is addressing this in Magento 2, [which is available on github](https://github.com/magento/magento2).

> "[Why are there] a million directories (sarcasm) that I need to get into to make a modification[?] I assume they are using some kind of MVC model but it is by far nothing I have ever seen."

Magento is indeed an MVC framework, and a robust one at that. It is, as you've noticed, quite distinct, especially in the PHP frameworks realm.

- Models are PHP classes under `app/code/[codePool]/Namespace/ModuleName/`. By convention, they are under the `Model` directory. They come in three general flavors: data models, which conventionally reside directly under the `Model/` directory, and resource models & resource collections which conventionally reside under `Model/Resource` as of Magento 1.6.
- Views are PHP classes which conventionally reside under `app/code/[codePool]/Namespace/ModuleName/Block/`. They may or may not be rendered along with template files (`.phtml`). Unlike many MVC frameworks, Views in Magento often load their own data independent of route / action.
- Controllers are PHP classes which are found under app/code/[codePool]/Namespace/ModuleName/controllers/`.

> "If they are attempting to make pretty URLs with all these directories I'm pretty sure they have heard of htaccess."

Not at all. The only thing which connects URLs to action controllers is configuration (this is true of all MVC classes outside of the Mage namespace). SEF URLs are achievable via configuration in multiple ways as well as via database rewrites which may be found in `core_url_rewrite` table. Magento does use an `.htaccess` file only as a means of routing appropriate requests to the system entry point, `index.php`.

> "I looked into the phtml files and most of them look like their just calling these XML elements, is it possible to use plain old HTML and PHP to create a theme? Or am I forced to use their XML methods?"

Templates are dumb. They are pointless without the View class in which they are rendered - literally `included()`ed. The methods and data available to them come from their (often) layout-configured View class. For an example of view configuration, see **[app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/cms.xml](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.6/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/cms.xml)**: the `<block type="core/template" name="page_content_heading" template="cms/content_heading.phtml"/>` line declares an instance of `Mage_Core_Block_Template` with the `cms/content_heading.phtml` template from the frontend theme.

> "[T]he theme folder at app/design/frontend has two folders base and default which im thinking each of these are interfaces for example a group of themes i would like to use. i modified the design_change db"

It's good that you are investigating these things; an explorer's approach will be helpful as you learn the framework. Themes in Magento are defined by three components: an area (frontend or adminhtml), a package name, and an actual theme name. In the filesystem, these settings map out to two places, as you've noticed. They are `./app/design/AREA/PACKAGE/THEME/` and `./skin/AREA/PACKAGE/THEME/`. There are two more aspects to theming in Magento: theme asset type and fallback.

There are four theme asset types: layout, template, translation, and skin. The path that the system uses to find a given theme asset is based on configuration as well as some hardcoded paths. The absolute fallback point for theme assets is the *base* package's *default* theme. Appropriate Magento configuration has you first declaring a package (e.g. 'my_package' under System > Configuration > Design. With no theme settings declared, the system will simply look for assets under the *default* theme; this would map to `app/design/frontend/my_package/default/template/`. If you were to declare a "Templates" theme in Design configuration (e.g. "my_templates", the system would first look there and then look under the *default* theme. There is also a "Default" configuration setting which, if set, will be used for all theme asset types (e.g. "my_default"). This is all happening in `Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package` and it looks like the following; we'll use our example settings and the "cms/content_heading.phtml" param from above:

1. `app/design/frontend/my_package/my_templates/template/cms/content_heading.phtml` (if found, use this one, don't look anywhere else)
2. `app/design/frontend/my_package/my_default/template/cms/content_heading.phtml` (if found, use this one, don't look anywhere else)
3. `app/design/frontend/my_package/default/template/cms/content_heading.phtml` (if found, use this one, don't look anywhere else)
4. `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/cms/content_heading.phtml` (if not found here, someone screwed up, and an exception will be logged to the system log at `./var/log/system.log`)

This design fallback is used for two reasons: allows failsafe places for developers to store theme assets (base/default) and allows for multistore reuse and DRY overriding of theme assets.

That said, this is not an ideal architecture, and as mentioned, this is going away in Magento 2 - all theme assets will be stored inside their respective module's directory.

Comment: outstanding answer @Ben. I think the ability to dynamically construct XML layouts via incremental additions, removals and modifications by independent modules is one of the most underrated, unjustly hated and misused features of Magento. It is best practice in other large-scale ecommerce frameworks and represents one of the enterprise-quality maturities in Magento that is worth investing the time to understand.

Comment: Awesome answer, my only gripe is why use XML and not just a PHP native multidimensional array and save all that processing of SimpleXML and caching?  Not too mention how many times I've been burned by fat fingering a node or case sensitivity. Maybe would be better as a question on here.

Comment: @B00MER there is no definitive answer on this. I hope to find one some day. My best guess is that there is/was a desire for the layout instructions to be exposed/accessible outside of raw PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Only reading will be able to help you much here. Once you get the hang of it, the xml layouts are pretty handy, it's just a pain learning how they work.

You can indeed ignore a lot of the xml stuff if and just put stuff inside the template files, but as you will read from other sources, it's not always best practice to work this way (though I'm sure every Magento developer does it on occasion).

Your best reference is often the Magento code itself. So long as you never touch anything inside base/default, you will always have a reference of how it's "supposed" to work.

Magento is definitely a Swiss Army Tool. You can get things done in many ways, each of which has it's pros and cons. Sometimes hardcoding stuff into templates/layouts is the way to go... sometimes you need to use static blocks and CMS (if a client wants to be able to edit something, for example).

Again, keep at it.. it is certainly frustrating to learn, but you will eventually pick up on the nuances and will start to feel more comfortable.

Comment: thank you for your posting, i am kind of forced to learn this lol what i was wondering though is magento uses prototype JS. if i were to somehow remove this and replace it with jquery for the frontend design only, will something break?

Comment: use jQuery in noconflict mode rather than trying to swap out -all- the prototype code IMO.

Comment: Prototype is fairly entrenched throughout. jQuery will be the js framework used for Magento 2, however.

Comment: There's a Magento theme on themeforest called Acumen which has reduced some of the JS bloat to an extent. Removing prototype will indeed break a ton of stuff, some of it easy to account for, most of it not. If you want to rewrite all of that, you can be my guest, otherwise you may take a similar approach as the Acumen theme and reduce what isn't needed, but be careful of extensions that may break as a result.